# fill a column proportionally based on a list of values (which may vary)

Tags: r

Fill a column proportionally based on a list of values (which may vary)
Exemple:

```
  id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
  id <-  as.data.frame(id)

 names <- c("Jean", "Jules", "Lina")
 names <-  as.data.frame(names)
```

Expected output:

```
 id names
 1 Jean
 2 Jean
 3 Jean
 4 Jules
 5 Jules
 6 Jules
 7 Lina
 8 Lina
 9 Lina
 10 Lina
```

I must adapt my second column values with any list like this example :

```
  id2 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,11)
  id2 <-  as.data.frame(id2) 
  names2 <- c("Jean", "Jules", "Lina", "Fred")
  names2 <-  as.data.frame(names2)
```

Expected output :

```
  id2 names2
  1 Jean
  2 Jean
  3 Jean
  4 Jules
  5 Jules
  6 Jules
  7 Lina
  8 Lina
  9 Lina
 10 Fred
 11 Fred
```

How to do this?

Comment: Proportional to what exactly? As a follow-up why is "Lina" present 4 times in `names` but only 3 in `names2`?

Comment: All the sequence of names must be the same size expected the last name that may be different.

Comment: If this is an exercise, you should try to do it yourself, and tell us what you have tried.

Comment: Sorry, I am just looking for help to solve my problem. I don't know how to begin (base R, dplyr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the number of repetitions by dividing the number of lines by the number of names, then use [tidyr::fill](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/fill.html) to fill missing values.

```
# Number of repetitions:
n <- nrow(id) %/% nrow(names)

# Repeat names
repnames <- rep(names$names, each = n)

# Make the names vector the same length as id
repnames <- repnames[1:nrow(id)]

# Change it to a data frame
repnames <- data.frame(names = repnames)

# Add id column
repnames$id <- id$id

# Fill the missing value
repnames <- tidyr::fill(repnames, names)

repnames
# 
#    names id
# 1   Jean  1
# 2   Jean  2
# 3   Jean  3
# 4  Jules  4
# 5  Jules  5
# 6  Jules  6
# 7   Lina  7
# 8   Lina  8
# 9   Lina  9
# 10  Lina 10
```

Comment: Thank you for helping using  tidyr::fill

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't transform your vectors into data frames, there's really no need to do it.
Now, the following function returns a vector matching your expected column, only then create a df.

```
fun <- function(x, y){
    m <- length(x)
    n <- length(y)
    new <- rep(y, each = round(m/n))
    if(m - n*round(m/n) > 0)
        new <- c(new, rep(y[n], m - n*round(m/n)))
    else
        new <- new[seq_len(m)]
    new
}

result1 <- data.frame(id, names1 = fun(id, names1))
result2 <- data.frame(id2, names2 = fun(id2, names2))
```

Note that I've changed the name of vector `names` to `names1`, since `names` already is a `base R` function.